# Overlaying text from YouTube API on image thumbnail

Tags: php, api, youtube

I've setup a script that displays recent video thumbnails from a YouTube playlist using the the data API.

I'd like to grab the first three characters from $title and overlay it on a thumbnail, how can I grab this information and display it? I can do the CSS, I'm just unsure of how to call it.

Current progress is in the videos pod at...

Current PHP code is:

```
<?php
get_playlists();

function get_playlists(){
$data = file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/C82EBDAC0429B6A2?                  orderby=published&max-results=12");
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

foreach($xml->entry as $playlist){
$media = $playlist->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
$attrs = $media->group->thumbnail[1]->attributes();
$thumb = $attrs['url'];
$attrs = $media->group->player->attributes();
$video = $attrs['url'];
$title = substr( $media->group->title, 27);
$url = $video;

parse_str( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_QUERY ), $my_array_of_vars );
$vid_Id = $my_array_of_vars['v'];

$thumbnail .= '<div style="float:left; cursor:pointer;">
<p class="crop"><a class="videobox various iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' .     $vid_Id . '?autoplay=1&hd=1"><img src="' .$thumb . '" title="' . $title . '" width="74"     height="56"/></a></p></div>';
}print $thumbnail;}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$title = substr($media->group->title, 0, 3);
```

you can display the first 3 characters of the title by echoing this variable:

```
echo $title;
```

Comment: I'd like to display the first 3 characters of the **original** title, without interfering with the other substr that is already there. Because I'm going to grab the numbers to make it look something like this http://d.pr/i/G8oR (Ignore the numbers on the tooltip, I'm not having the numbers there)

Comment: Could anybody assist me with this?